# Редактирование реестра другой ОС на одном компе

Tags: windows, delphi, реестр

**Уважаемые, прошу Вашей помощи.** Хочу в своем редакторе реестра, написанном на **Delphi**, сделать следующую опцию. Загрузить, записать значение из реестра другой ОС. 
 Т.е. у меня стоит две ОС: одна на диске С, другая на D - как мне прочитать и записать параметры реестра из одной ОС в реестр другой ОС?

Объяснение: имеется Edit на форме, в него ввожу значение, нажимаю кнопку записать, выдается форма для выбора реестра, если две ОС стоят, там выбираю нужную ОС и нажимаю ок. И так же нужно прочитать значение ключа реестра.

Comment: Что делать? Прочитать внимательно MSDN.

"The calling process must have the SE_RESTORE_NAME and SE_BACKUP_NAME privileges on the computer in which the registry resides. For more information, see Running with Special Privileges. To load a hive without requiring these special privileges, use the RegLoadAppKey function."

Очень интересным представляется последнее приложение. Как получить эти привилегии - см. <a href=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717802.aspx>MSDN далее</a>.

Answer (score 1):

Для редактирования реестра разных ОСей используются разные механизмы. Связано это с тем, что реестр загруженной ОС модифицировать через файлы нельзя - только через документированный интерфейс ОС, который правит реестр в памяти. Для этого предназначены ф-ции Win32API для работы с реестром. Их описание можно найти [тут](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724875.aspx). А вот чтобы отредактировать реестр в оффлайн режиме нужно или вручную открыть файл реестра и реализовать работу с ним, или использовать механизм загрузки куста. Тогда с загруженным кустом можно работать стандартными ф-циями. По завершении работы с реестром незагруженной копии ОС - куст выгружаете и он синхронизируется с содержимым на винчестере.

Comment: Если б речь шла про W9x - я б сказал, что редактируйте напрямую, т.к. там файлы реестра были текстовые и особенных проблем не возникало. Сейчас же ситуация такова, что файл реестра представляет собой бинарный файл. Скорее всего туда сохраняется реестр как дерево. И т.к. это внутренности операционной системы, то открытой документации как это делать нет. Но можно разобраться. Возьмите исходные коды reactos, подизассмеблируйте windows, поищите по интернету - возможно кто-то формат раскопал.

Comment: Чтобы загрузить куст нужно воспользоваться ф-цией <a href=Чтобы загрузить куст нужно воспользоваться ф-цией [RegLoadKey][1]

[1] : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724889.aspx>RegLoadKey</a>

Comment: procedure TForm1.sBitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
  begin
 mdv_Reg      := TRegistry.Create;
 mdv_Reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
 RegLoadKey(mdv_Reg.RootKey, 'SFT', 'D:/system32/config_izm/SOFTWARE');
  end;

Comment: Заведите временную переменную типа longint. Сохраните в нее результат вызова RegLoadKey:

`hRet := RegLoadKey(mdv_Reg.RootKey, 'SFT', 'D:/system32/config_izm/SOFTWARE');`

А затем проверьте его. Посмотреть какие возвращаемые значения о чем сигнализируют можно посмотреть в справке MSDN по данной ф-ции.

Comment: Для расшифровки этого кода можно использовать ф-цию `FormatMessage` из WinAPI. Или программу `errlook.exe` из комплекта MS Visual Studio. В данном случае она мне сказала, что это ошибка "Клиент не обладает требуемыми правами."

Comment: И что делать